# How to change prefix in jhipster with AngularX

Tags: angular, jhipster

I want to change prefix of jhi to custom in jhipster + Angular 4.

I have tried the following command:

```
yo jhipster:app --skip-install --skip-user-management --jhi-prefix app --npm --skip-cache
```

But it doesn't work. I am creating a monolithic application with mongodb and internationalization.

Comment: [The docs](http://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#-command-line-options) suggest that should work, so if it doesn't you'll need to raise an issue with the maintainers. See e.g. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6003 - depending on your version you should upgrade, edit `.yo-rc.json` yourself or raise another issue if it's a regression.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the property value of ***jhiPrefix*** based on the requirement in **.yo-rc.json**

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.sample"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.7.0",
    .....
    .....
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    ........
  }
}
```

Now rerun the

> yo jhipster